# Vuejs shows the same data on multiple components

Tags: vue.js

I have the following component chain in my project (templates are in different vue files, here ... acts as a separator to make it readable):

```
<!-- Sensors template -->
<div class="container">
  <div class= "sensors_item"> 
  <SensorItem v-for="i in sensors" :sensordata="i" :key="sensors.id"></SensorItem>         
  </div>
</div>
...
<!-- SensorItem template -->
 <div>
   <SensorParameterItem v-for="i in sensordata.sensorparams" :parameterdata="i" :key="sensordata.sensorparams.id"></SensorParameterItem>
 </div>
...
<!-- SensorParameterItem template -->
  <div class="col parameter-icon-clickable" v-on:click="openChart">
      <i class="fas fa-chart-line" color="white"></i>
  </div>
  </div>
      <ChartCollapsible class="parameter-icon-clickable" :isOpen="isChartOpen" :pdata="parameterdata"/>
  </div
...
<!-- ChartCollapsible template-->
<div>
  <transition appear name="modal">
      <div v-if="isOpen">
        <div class="chart-container">
          <apexcharts height="400" width="100%"  ref="chart" type="area" :options="o1" :series="setSeries"></apexcharts>
          <!-- OK -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </transition>
</div>
...
Functions
...
openChart: function() {

  let data = {count: 144};
  console.log('openChart');
  this.$store.dispatch('getsensordata', data)
  this.isChartOpen = !this.isChartOpen;
}
...
computed: {
setSeries() {
  console.log("Computed.")
  if(this.$store.getters.authStatus == "received") {
      this.s1 = _.cloneDeep(this.$store.getters.getData);
  } else {
    this.s1 = _.cloneDeep([{data: [{x:0,y:0}]}]);
  }

  return this.s1;
}
```

}

I'm calling the backend by clicking in the SensorParameterItem (openChart fn) to receive chart data. Then, in ChartCollapsible I have computed which verifies that new data is received. After that it deep copies the new data into a property and returns that property to the chart component. I'd expect that each ChartCollapsible component would have its own chart data but it's not: I have 10 ChartCollapsibles rendered and all is updated with the same data, when I click any openchart button.
Any help would be great how to solve this issue!

Comment: It's really hard to understand right now, could you give us a minimal reproducable example in the codepen?

Comment: Hi Tadas, thank you for dropping by, I've just found my error and a possible fix, see it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've found what caused this behaviour: there is a computed property in the component, which monitors this.$store.getters.authStatus == "received" state. Since ALL component instances monitor this single state, when it changes, ALL component instances will be updated.
A possible fix is to send some component specific data (title, id, etc.) along this.$store.dispatch('getsensordata', data) request which will be replied back to all component instances, but only one component will be updated:

```
computed: {
setSeries() {
  if(this.$store.getters.authStatus == "received") {

    // Filter down to our chart otherwise all charts will be updated!
    if(this.header.title == this.$store.getters.getData.header.title && this.parameterdata.pidx == this.$store.getters.getData.header.pidx) {
      this.s1 = _.cloneDeep(this.$store.getters.getData.data);         
      }
  }
  return this.s1;
}
```

}